# Turn syntax off only for current buffer/window?

Tags: vimdiff, syntax

Is there a way to turn off syntax for only the current buffer/split windows? like for example, you can set `map <buffer>` or `setlocal`. Is there something similar for the `syntax` option ?

I use the `:diffsplit` command in vim quite a bit, for which I prefer to disable syntax and but this turns off highlighting for all buffers. I am using the following settings :

```
" turn off syntax when started from terminal
if &diff 
    syntax off
endif 
" turn off syntax when started from inside vim 
au OptionSet diff syntax off
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buffers and windows are different things.

To clear syntax for a particular buffer you can set the `syntax` option to empty string (or even simply do `:syntax clear` which should be the same for most purposes).

To clear syntax in a particular window you could use `:ownsyntax off`.

Comment: thanks that was helpful. `:ownsyntax off` does the trick. Is there a way to turn the syntax back on automatically after `:q` uitting from one of the windows using some kind of autocommand ?

Comment: @FirstUser Obviously, `&diff` will be auto-reset after only single "diffed"-window remains open.